# erreur upload image php

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, xampp

I have the following error:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(avatar/essai.jpg): failed to open stream:
*... Permission not granted in /opt/lampp/htdocs/site/submitfunc.php ...*

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/opt/lampp/temp/php2FwMbY' to 'avatar/essai.jpg' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/site/submitfunc.php on line 3

*when I press confirm to load the image*

*Here is my function submitfunc.php:*

```
<?php
//la fonction qui va changer l'image de profil
//function that will change the profile picture
move_uploaded_file($avatar_tmp,'avatar/'.$avatar);
mysql_query("

UPDATE membres SET avatar='{$_FILES['avatar']['name']}' WHERE nom='{$_SESSION['nom']}'

");

?>
```

*I use xampp on ubuntu*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the documentation on the function is always a good place to start:
  [fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.move-uploaded-file.php](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.move-uploaded-file.php)
  [www.php.net/move_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file)

> Si **filename** n'est pas valide, rien ne se passe, et move_uploaded_file() retournera FALSE.
>
> Si **filename** est un fichier téléchargé, mais que pour une raison
>   quelconque, il ne peut être déplacé, rien ne se passe, et
>   move_uploaded_file() retourne FALSE. *De plus, une alerte sera
>   affichée.*
>
> If **filename** is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and
>   move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.
>
> If **filename** is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some
>   reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return
>   FALSE. *Additionally, a warning will be issued.*

The warning message indicates that your Apache process does not have permission to access/write to your destination folder. Use the Linux command `chmod` to adjust the folder's permission settings to allow apache access.

Comment: all files have the rwx permission in the site folder, even the file that i will upload :/

Comment: And the folder itself as well?

Comment: mmm i guess no , let me sheck that

Comment: perfect :) i forgot the main php file without permissions :/ i change the permissions of the folder too and its working :) thank you faintsignal

Comment: Pas de problème. By the way, your English definitely seems pretty good. Posting questions on stackoverflow in English is encouraged, you will receive more feedback this way. Good luck with your project.

Comment: i make a lot of mistakes sometimes  :) that's why i use French  generally. but i will try to use English  :)  thx again